# iPhone: Store Graphics Path as Constant

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

I have a bunch of paths defined like the following:

```
_shapeMutablePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(_shapeMutablePath, NULL, 95.97,36.29);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(_shapeMutablePath, NULL, 96.02,29.11,90.75,23.00,83.54,21.40);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(_shapeMutablePath, NULL, 62.64,66.59,64.11,66.96,65.66,67.12);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(_shapeMutablePath, NULL, 74.52,68.04,82.49,62.03,83.47,53.69);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(_shapeMutablePath, NULL, 83.57,52.83,83.59,51.98,83.54,51.15);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(_shapeMutablePath, NULL, 90.74,49.56,96.01,43.45,95.97,36.29);
CGPathCloseSubpath(_shapeMutablePath);
```

Some of them I have to reuse quite frequently, so I was wondering what is the best way to store and retrieve this information? Is it possible to save it as a constant in my constants file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The computing time to create a path is nothing compared to the time for drawing it on screen, so it shouldn't be a problem to create it on-demand with a static method or something

Alternatively, you could make a static class that stores the different paths you want to re-use

Answer (score 0):

You could always just lazy load like this

Add a property

```
@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) CGMutablePathRef shapeMutablePath;
```

Then override the getter

```
- (CGMutablePathRef)shapeMutablePath;
{
  if (!_shapeMutablePath) {
    _shapeMutablePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(_shapeMutablePath, NULL, 95.97,36.29);
    CGPathAddCurveToPoint(_shapeMutablePath, NULL, 96.02,29.11,90.75,23.00,83.54,21.40);
    CGPathAddCurveToPoint(_shapeMutablePath, NULL, 62.64,66.59,64.11,66.96,65.66,67.12);
    CGPathAddCurveToPoint(_shapeMutablePath, NULL, 74.52,68.04,82.49,62.03,83.47,53.69);
    CGPathAddCurveToPoint(_shapeMutablePath, NULL, 83.57,52.83,83.59,51.98,83.54,51.15);
    CGPathAddCurveToPoint(_shapeMutablePath, NULL, 90.74,49.56,96.01,43.45,95.97,36.29);
    CGPathCloseSubpath(_shapeMutablePath);
  }
  return _shapeMutablePath;
}
```

You'll also need to clean up in dealloc

```
- (void)dealloc;
{
  CGPathRelease(_shapeMutablePath);
}
```